# how can create USDT wallet address in nodejs and web3.js in ERC20

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, erc20, trx

I have 2 networks. TRC-20 and ERC-20 networks.

Now I want to use different coins on my site. For example, USDT, Doge, Bitcoin, and any currency in the ERC-20 and TRc-20 networks.

When a user wants to transfer money from my site to a Binance site or any other site, that site gives the user a Wallet address to which I must transfer the money.

For example, it wants to transfer the USDT to Binance. I created a wallet address for this user with web.js `web.eth.createAccount` ,  Does it matter what token this address is made for?

Or can I use the same for USDT?

Do I have to do anything for the user when creating a wallet to create a USDT wallet on the ERc-20 network?

The next question is how should I buy the real USDT and deposit it in this person's account? Do I have to have a USDT account myself and transfer from that account to that person?